# Angular2/Rxjs HTTP Catch Asynchronous Transform Issue

Tags: angular, try-catch, rxjs, angular2-observables

I'm attempting to call an HTTP Post method in Angular 2 to retrieve a PDF file, so I'm setting the ResponseContentType to be Blob, like this:

```
let headers = new Headers({
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'ApplicationName': 'ControlEnroll',
        'Accept': 'application/pdf'
    });
let options = new RequestOptions({
        headers: headers,
        responseType: ResponseContentType.Blob
    });
```

Now, I have no problem with when the `post()` call is a success, but when it is an error I am having problems with pulling out the error message returned from my WebAPI method because it is wrapped in a Blob.

Since this is Angular 2, my `post()` call and structure looks like this right now:

```
return this.http.post(postUrl, {
        // ... some body parameters here ...
    }, options)
        .map(resp => {
            let blob: Blob = resp.blob();
            // Use the file-save library to persist this to disk.
            window['saveAs'](blob, 'File.pdf');

            return resp;
        }).catch(error => {
            // What to do?
        });
```

The problem is in the `catch()` method I know that the `error` being provided is a Response object containing a Blob body. The only way to extract the text from the Blob object that I know of is to use a FileReader and an event listener, like this:

```
let body = error.json();
let reader = new FileReader();

reader.addEventListener('loadend', function () {
    console.log(reader.result);
});

reader.readAsText(body);
```

However, this won't happen immediately; it's an event listener. Yet, the `catch()` must [likey] `throw` an error of some sort out to the outside that is Observable, right? How can I handle this `catch()` method in a way that will let me pull the string out of the Blob, yet allow someone else to subscribe to this entire method and use the normal `subscribe(successFn, errorFn)` structure? Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The selector function passed to the `catch` operator can return an observable that will be used to continue the observable chain in the event of an error.

So your selector function can return an observable that waits for the `loadend` event from the `FileReader` and then throws an error with the message you've read from the BLOB. Something like this:

```ts
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/fromEvent';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/do';

...
.catch(error => {
  let reader = new FileReader();
  let loadend = Observable.fromEvent(reader, 'loadend');
  reader.readAsText(error.blob());
  return loadend.do(() => { throw new Error(reader.result /* or whatever */); });
})
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I believe I needed a set of braces {} at the bottom of your example snippet in the lambda clause, as it wouldn't work on my end without them, but otherwise that was exactly what I was missing. I did not realize that Observables had a `fromEvent` wrapper to convert an event to an Observable, and the `do` method to allow the `throw` to occur later worked a treat. I'm still getting the hang of these Observables after having spent a long time on Promises, but this was great. Thanks again.

Comment: No worries. Added the `{}`.

Comment: BTW, you should probably check for the presence of the `blob` method on the `error`. If there's no connectivity, for example, I would not be surprised if you get a non-response error, so to speak. In which case, you might want to just re-throw the received error, etc.